# Performance issue with 1k to 10k websites/ stores

Tags: multistore

I am trying to find a way to improve Magento performance when the amount of websites/ stores exceeds 1k, and my goal is around 10k. Here are some questions; any tips/ helps are extremely welcome!

1. Adding new websites/ stores is slow;
   I comment out $this->cleanModelCache() in _afterSave() in Mage_Core_Model_Abstract, and the situation seems better but is getting slower with increasing number of websites/ stores. And I don't know what would this affect the whole system in the future.
2. Api calls become slow.
   One of the main processes is to place order; my customized model deals with it by processing some data, and essentially using sales/quote model and sales/service_quote models. The process begins with Oauth. Both Oauth and placing order take longer when the number of website/ store grows, and the memory consumption seems larger. Does this have something to do with Mage loading the config xml, and the fact that config data gets bigger with increasing number of websites?
3. Opening up n98-magerun dev:console is taking longer; don't know the cause of it.
4. Saving configuration from admin panel takes longer; don't know how to improve it.

Is it possible to reconstruct the way Magento generate and load config data to lower its memory consumption? Is this one of the factors that cause performance issue for my situation?

Current Magento instance:
Version = Magento EE 1.14.2.4;
Config cache on; other cache off;
Using Mysql 5.6 and MongoDB( for catalog_category_entity, catalog_product_entity, core_website);
number of websites = number of stores = number of views = 1024;
number of product = 4501;

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: why magento support can not help you???

Comment: How do I get help from them? I am new to the community.. thanks!

Comment: you have enterprise version, not sure where you get it, but if there is no magento support behind it, just wasted money and time. you must well hit them in the balls to make them run like rabbits helping you. what is the point in having enterprise version???

Comment: but obvious answer to your query is - separate magento shops with separate databases, like batches per 10-20 shops...

Comment: Ah right.. I am gonna ask my boss for the account..haha.

Comment: au, i remember there will be also EE licence limitation :) LOL

Comment: Do you have a small army of monkeys to manage 10k stores?

Answer (score 3):

One of the reasons it gets slow is because the configuration for each store is duplicated from /config/websites and /config/global and the code for doing that is not efficient in the least.  Any setting change may end up causing several 10's of minutes, if not hours, of reduced performance and throughput.  Making it more efficient will basically mean that Ben Marks will come after you... and not in a good way.

IF you are going to go down this route the easiest way would be to have 10k Magento installations and have some kind of a broker that delegates requests to the appropriate website.  Though it will, of course, depend on what your actual use case is.

[added]

Depending on the use case you might be able to use categories as pseudo stores.  You could technically then use layout XML to change the theming per store.  But then you would run into the limitation of checkout.  All stores would need to share the checkout.

Either way, 10k Magento stores is do-able, in that it is not impossible.  But it will be a difficult road whatever path you choose.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you for your reply! Yes I see the code that updates config tree, which is loadToXml() if I am not wrong. My thought is; and you said it is not a good idea to modify it? What do you mean by Ben Marks coming after me?   Also, it seems that each http request that comes to Magento will eventually load config tree, is that correct? Any way that I can shrink the size of it?       I should probably think about getting 10k Magento instances... any thoughts on how much resource that would need? Thank you very much Kevin!

Comment: But having 10k Magento installations means 10k mysql instances right? I have no idea how to do this, or if it is a good idea..

Comment: No, it would mean having 10k mysql databases, but all 10k of them could be in a single mysql instance.

Comment: Right.. Do you know about the performance when there's over 10k databases in mysql? I haven't tried out yet, but I am concerned..

Comment: The "Ben Marks" coming after you is a reference to this https://camo.githubusercontent.com/0043e9f9ea1412204dbebf6edfb8a6703c169539/68747470733a2f2f64323169693931693379366f36682e636c6f756466726f6e742e6e65742f67616c6c6572795f696d616765732f66726f6d5f70726f6f662f31313232332f6c617267652f313435383331343231362f6865792d6469642d796f752d6a7573742d656469742d7468652d636f72652e706e67

Comment: 10k Magento installations means 10k MySQL databases, however that would be spread out.  It would be MUCH easier to script deploying 10k individual Magento installations than it would be to make the existing core code work with 10k stores.

Comment: Haha I see, that was funny, and crucial...

Answer (score 1):

You can try hacking the core and enabling website cache splits.
You can try hacking the database and storing configuration information in memory.
You can try replacing the configuration cache with something smarter - say caching the information from the xml files[which are static and apply to all websites and stores] while retrieving the override data dynamically.

I'm a server guy, so I'd go with mucking with the database.  Especially since it is trivial to do.

If you have control over your database server:
Rename the core_config_data table to core_config_data_offline
Create a new core_config_data table using the MEMORY storage engine
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html
Copy all the data from core_config_data_offline to core_config_data

Setup a cron job to check to see if core_config_data exists, if it does copy all the data from there to core_config_data_offline.  If it does not, create it and copy everything from core_config_data_offline to core_config_data

Turn off the config cache.  With the config cache turned on, you only get a performance boost for the first time config data is read from the database - after that it is in the cache and you suffer.  On the downside the xml files are no longer cached, so you traded the performance hit of unserializing huge configuration data for the performance hit of parsing a bunch of xml files.

You may also want to experiment with changing the Mage/Core/Model/Config.php file and enable individual website caches. By default each store specific configuration data is cached individually.  All the website configuration data is cached in one object.

Note that this is just for the configuration overrides[the admin settings].  So if you do all your configuration changes at the store level your already set.  If your using "inherit from website" and making most of your store specific configuration changes at the site level - then the cache contains every website.  By splitting it you can break it out much better.
    protected $_cacheSections = array(
        'admin'     => 0,
        'adminhtml' => 0,
        'crontab'   => 0,
        'install'   => 0,
        'stores'    => 1,
        'websites'  => 0
    );

to

```
protected $_cacheSections = array(
    'admin'     => 0,
    'adminhtml' => 0,
    'crontab'   => 0,
    'install'   => 0,
    'stores'    => 1,
    'websites'  => 1
);
```

Comment: Hi Gary, thank you for such a helpful reply! I have some questions: 1) From my observation, database query is not an issue, even with over 1k websites/ stores; so if that is the case, would using memory storage still help?    2) I don't know if it is correct, but config cache seems to store only system and modules information; so does it have something to do with website/ store configuration?    3) Is there a way for magento to recognize a specific store/ website id from an http request, and thus load only the corresponding config file?     Thank you very much Gary!

Comment: These recommendations don't address the problem the OP was noting.  Turning off the configuration cache will ultimately kill the system.  It will cause Magento to load up all of the configuration files, merge them, then merge all of /global then merge all of /websites and then merge all of that into each /stores node.  That will happen for EACH request.  With 10k sites you could be looking at minutes of wall clock time *per request*.

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks for the reply; Actually I am planning to move the core_config_data table into the memory, enable cache for system and module config, stop core_config_data from being merged into the config tree, and make functions that read this part of data directly query from database. What do you think?

Comment: The problem is not core_config_data.  The problem is that store configs are merged from /websites which are merged from /global in XML  The database will be perfectly fine.  It is PHP that will be hating life because of the configuration merges.  In your debugger step through Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Config::loadToXml paying special attention to lines 110 and following

Comment: Hey Kevin, yes I understand this is not a db issue, and that is why I am trying to stop Magento from merging all the web/ store config into the XML. And for all the query to the XML for web/ store config, I make them query mysql directly. Is this even possible thought...? Thank you again for your precious time! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Sure, it's possible to query MySQL directly, but without the configuration merge you will be missing a good deal of information that is set in the config.xml files.

Comment: Start with how Magento deals with determining a simple configuration:  All the xml configuration files are read and merged into a single object.   After that the all the configuration data from the core_config table are merged into the configuration object.  Then each time a variable is needed from the configuration data, the configuration object is checked for that data.   The configuration object can be[is] cached so that in future requests Magento does not need to merge all the xml files and then merge in the database table.

Comment: Given the above, moving on to a multi-website, multi-store system.  Every configuration item has a scope and a scope-id.   The scope determines if the configuration is global, specific to a website, or specific to a store.  The scope id can further differentiate it - ie the configuration is specific to the store configuration and applies to a specific store id.  Or it is website specific and applies to a specific website id.   When Magento looks up a configuration value it will check for the most specific[store based, store id] and move up the chain.

Comment: So let's apply caching using the above information.  For every store id, the configuration information specific for that store is cached in it's own cache file/object[defined by the array $_cacheSections above].   All other configuration data, websites, global, etc are stored in a single cache.  Note: this only applies to OVERRIDES.  If your store inherits configuration from a the website, then the value will not be cached with the store configuration.

Comment: If most of your configuration overrides are done at the WEBSITE level Magento has to parse through the massive configuration cache of all data to retrieve a configuration value.  So that's where changing the value of $_cacheSections can help - for each potential cachable configuration set, if the cache section is set to 1 the data is segregated and cached seperately for that specific scope id.   If the cache section is set to 0 - which is all of them except store - then it all goes to one place.   So that is a quick item to test, just change the value from websites from 0 to 1 and test

Comment: Now to come back to my memory table.  Caching data means to store it somewhere that can be accessed quickly.  Magento caches configuration data into a php serialized object - if your configuration data is huge that means PHP has to deserialize a huge amount of data for every request.  If you know how to use xdebug, profile some of your slower page loads and look at how much time is spent running the unserialize function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php  - if it's huge[over 100ms] then "caching" the configuration is breaking your system.

Comment: I refuse to be limited to only one way of doing things.   Since caching is just a way to access the underlying data quickly, if you DISABLE the configuration cache and MOVE the configuration table to a memory table you are still caching configuration data - your just doing it outside of Magento.   Now Magento will try to read individual cache overrides from a memory table - an incredibly fast set of queries that will return a small set of data - avoiding memory/speed issues.

Comment: Note: the gain from the memory table is offset by a performance loss in that all the xml config files will be read and merged for every request.  This is almost always a bad idea in general - but I don't care about in general, I care about your case specifically. Which means you need to duplicate your production system to a dev/testing system and experiment there.  The tweaks are small and should take less time to test then reading all my comments here took. :-)  Or post Xdebug profiles for review: https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler